# Undertsanding Laplace Transform output

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, control-theory

According to this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRazT.png) using the Laplace Transform, I am just curious to HOW we go from

$Y(s)=\frac{32}{s*(s^2+12s+32)}$

to

$Y(s)=\frac{32}{s*(s+4)*(s+8)}$

More specific, I am curious to why we get an 4 and an 8. What formula or equation are being used to get those numbers? I know that the Laplace Transform calculates it for us, however, I want to calculate it "by hand" and show why we get the answer. Any feedback would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUMhpKGwpCY

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that video!

Comment: @MattiP. Hey again, I hope it's okay I ping you. I just saw the video you linked and it all makes sense now, so thank you so much for that. I actually have a quick question. When factoring the polynomials, the video only shows what to do for "K" and "K*x". What happens with the s^2? Why is it left out in the solution of mine? Moreover, how come we don't do anything with the "s" to the far left? It all makes sense, I just want to know what we are doing exactly.

Comment: The first $s$ is already factored out, it doesn't need to be incorporated anymore. That's why we can just forget about it and focus on the expression $s^2 + 12s +32$.

Comment: @MattiP. How is it factored out exactly? In my example, it is still on the left side?

Comment: The linked transfer function seems wrong: it is third order although the differential equation is only second order. Where does the pole at $s = 0$ come from?

Comment: Well, it is my professor who came up with the equations, we just calculated them via Maple. The professor linked this as a solution to the problem, so I HOPE this is not wrong?

Comment: @NemanjaVuksanovic I just realized that there is no $U(s)$ so he seems to be using $U(s) = \frac{1}{s}$ which is the Laplace transform of a step input.

Comment: The professor uses $U(t)$ as the step-function where t is mostly time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(s+4)*(s+8) = s^2+12s+32$.

Comment: I see, @Matti P. pointed that out with a video referring to factoring polynomials. I am now curious as to what would happen if we had a 3-degree polynomial, would we do the same? Moreover, why is our "s" on the far left not touched? I mean, do we always to let it be as it's own, when we are factoring polynomials and braces?

Comment: Yes, @Matti P's answer was perfect. If you had had a degree 3 polynomial, then factoring it would have meant finding its (complex) roots. I'm not sure I understand the second half of your question though, since factoring a product of polynomials comes down to factoring each one.

Comment: I see, it makes total sense now. a little side-question. If you look at the linked image, you can see at the bottom the answer I got using the inverse Laplace transform. Using the information you guys feeded me with, I understand the answer mostly, however, I am just curious to why we get an "-2*e^-4t", where does the "-2" come from?

Comment: Hint : link this to K1, K2 and K3

Comment: I am so sorry, I can't really see it. I know K_1 is 1, K_2 is e^(-4t) and k_3 is e^(-8t). K_2 and K_3 is not that different from each other, so I would assume you need to multiply K_2 to get the value of K_3 perhaps?

Comment: No No No. From the third line $Y(s) = ...$, put the sum of fractions on the right with a single denominator, and then find the $K_i$s.

Comment: So you want me to do $\frac{K_1+K_2+K_3}{(s + (s + 4) + (s + 8))}$?

Comment: Further hint : $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad+bc}{bd}$

Comment: Then I get $\frac{K_1*(s+4)+s*K_2}{s*(s+4)}$ is this right?

Comment: Not quite. Where are $K_3$ and $(s+8)$ ?

Comment: Hmmm, trying your formula I get $\frac{K_1*(s+4)+s*K_2+(s+8)*K_3}{s*(s+4)*(s+8)}$ What you think about this?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but ... what is your background in algebra ? It feels like you're trying things at random, not understanding anything you're doing.

Comment: I am at my 2 year at engineering at uni, studying It and electronics. I have never used this formula or worked with the Laplace transform before, so sorry in advance if I am asking a lot of questions.

Comment: I understand, but your difficulties have nothing to do with the Laplace transform, but rather with basic algebra. In my opinion, you will find it useful to work it up to be able to effortlessly compute things like => https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A%2FB%2BC%2FD%2BE%2FF

Comment: I see. The course I am taking don't require me to do much algebra, but mostly talk about it and calculate the equations via other programs, however, I am just generally curious to why we get an "-2" in our equation, with that I can then read up on the algebra required to calculate it.

Comment: I guess this would be the right answer then? $\frac{K__1*(s + 4)*(s + 8) + K__2*s*(s + 8) + K__3*s*(s + 4)}{s*(s + 8)*(s + 4)}$

(I have no idea why this will not format correctly?)

Comment: Yes. Now, how can you use this to deduce the values of the $K_i$s? You can find help in the exemple section of this wikipedia article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

Comment: Hmm, looking at it, I would need a hint. Making the whole equation equal 32 just don't seem right to me? Furthermore, I have also looked at example 3, which also don't make much sense for my example.